# Unable to parse JSON from REST API call

Tags: python, json

I am not able to parse this JSON response from an API call, I want to extract the plate value (KA40M9202) .

```
api_response = api_instance.recognize_bytes(params,...,...,...,...)

pprint (api_response)
```

The following is printed

```
{'results': [{'candidates': [{'confidence': 70.61698913574219,
                                  'matches_template': 0,
                                  'plate': 'KA40M9202'},
                                 {'confidence': 65.3728256225586,
                                  'matches_template': 0,
                                  'plate': 'KA30M9202'},
                                 {'confidence': 65.3718490600586,
                                  'matches_template': 0,
                                  'plate': 'KA10M9202'}],
                  'matches_template': 0,
                  'plate': 'KA40M9202',
                  'processing_time_ms': 39.60576629638672,
                  }
```

On calling `json.loads()`, an error is shown

```
jsonstr = json.loads(api_response)
```

Errror message

```
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: technically that's not valid JSON. The property names should have double quotes (`"`) round them, not single quotes (`'`). After that you have a problem because there's a stray trailing comma (after the processing_time_ms_ property) and also a missing closing bracket. Are you sure that's all of the data? Are you sure the recognize_bytes method hasn't already deserialised it?

Comment: replace `'` with `"`, as `'` is not a valid json. `response.replace("'". '"')`

Comment: I believe that this is actually already deserialized by the REST library try to index it `api_response['results']`

Comment: @RobertWisner , i get the following error TypeError: 'InlineResponse200' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going through the documentation pointed by @L3viathan, I understand that the API response is a nested List.

```
i = 0  
if len(api_response.results) != 0:
    for i in api_response.results[0].candidates:
        print i.plate
```

The above code will fetch the required fields.

Answer (score 6):

The [OpenALPR bindings for Python](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/master/src/bindings/python/openalpr/openalpr.py) starting with `recognize_` all return

> An OpenALPR analysis in the form of a response dictionary

already, so there's no need to decode JSON.

**Edit:** It appears the docstrings lie a little, it returns an [`InlineResponse200`](https://github.com/openalpr/cloudapi/blob/8141c1ba57f03df4f53430c6e5e389b39714d0e0/python/openalpr_api/models/inline_response_200.py#L30) object, but its `.results` properties will give you the list of results.

Comment: i get the following error on print api_response["results"]
TypeError: 'InlineResponse200' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Try `api_response.results`. It's some weird kind of [pseudo-dictionary](https://github.com/openalpr/cloudapi/blob/master/python/docs/InlineResponse200.md).

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `pprint` call gives us a hint as to what's going on here. When `pprint` is called on a string (which a JSON response ought to be). it returns like so:

```
('{"results": [{"candidates": [{"confidence": 70.61698913574219, '
 '"matches_template": 0, "plate": "KA40M9202"}, {"confidence": '
 '65.3728256225586, "matches_template": 0, "plate": "KA30M9202"}, '
 '{"confidence": 65.3718490600586, "matches_template": 0, "plate": '
 '"KA10M9202"}], "matches_template": 0, "plate": "KA40M9202", '
 '"processing_time_ms": 39.60576629638672}]}')
```

that is to  say as tuple containing a string wrapped in single-quotes `'`, this tips us off that what we are getting back from our API call is not in fact a JSON string but rather a python data structure.